# Ruby named argument similar to javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If i have the following variables

```
const id = 123;
const item = "Clothes"
```

In ruby, a service call would be like `set_item(id: id, item: item)`.

Is there a way i can use the named arguments similar to javascript ?

something like `setItem({ id, item }}`.

That is,  `{id, item}`  instead of `id: id, item: item`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Rails doesn't have destructuring like that, you can return 2 or more from a method or multiple assignation as described below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by making these variables attributes of a class:

```rb
class Article
  attr_reader :id, :item

  def initialize(id, item)
    @id, @item = id, item
  end
end

id = 123
item = "Clothes"
article = Article.new(id, item)
```

Or with a method doing this assignation:

```rb
class Article
  attr_reader :id, :item

  def set_item(id, item)
    @id, @item = id, item
  end
end

id = 123
item = "Clothes"
article = Article.new
article.set_item(id, item)
```